# Resource on integration techniques and methods

Tags: calculus, integration, online-resources

I need resources on intermediate integration techniques in integration. I am not looking for simple methods like trigonometry substitution/integration by parts/partial fraction.

I have completed school and wish to know more on intermediate integration techniques in an orderly manner. Techniques I am looking for may be similar to feyman trick of differentiation.

I want to achieve excellence in integration methods, but in an ordered manner. Should I study real analysis first before proceeding?

Comment: Do you know multiple integration? That's the next, obvious step up, and when done right is very powerful. Do you know complex integration and residue theorem?

Comment: @kaynex No i don't know, have heard about it. So what course teaches that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to learn and better understand some of the various techniques that can be used to evaluate definite integrals, particularly improper integrals, following material that is reasonably well structured, the following texts can be consulted.

1. *Improper Riemann integrals* by Ioannis M. Roussos (CRC Press, 2014).
2. *A treatise on the integral calculus* (Volumes 1 & 2) by Joseph Edwards (MacMillian, 1921).
3. *Solved problems: Gamma and beta functions, Legendre polynomials, Bessel functions* by Orin J. Farrel and Bertram Ross (MacMillian, 1963).
4. *Integration for engineers and scientists* by W. Squire (Elsevier, 1970).
5. *Integral evaluations using the gamma and beta functions and elliptical integrals in engineering: A self-study approach* by C. C. Maican (International Press, 2005).

**Update**

6. *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series* by C. I. Valean (Springer, 2019).
7. *An Introduction to the Harmonic Series and Logarithmic Integrals: For High School Students up to Researchers* by Ali Shadhar Olaikhan (2021).

Comment: Thank you for good recommendations.. what are your thoughts on 'irresistable integrals' by Victor moll

Comment: *Irresistible Integrals* by Boros and Moll is much harder going and is perhaps better left until you have a solid foundation in the various standard methods used for finding definite/improper integrals.

Comment: I'll try the first and second or fifth. Second one seems too old.